# Access old-style Firefox extension's preferences when porting to WebExtensions

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My XUL-based Firefox extension stores data in preferences. Is there a way to access this data once when migrating to a WebExtension version?

I am aware of https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/FAQ#Does_the_WebExtensions_API_provide_access_to_preferences.3F but hope there is a solution for this specific use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of preferences, there are a few options:

- discard them and let your users set them again after upgrading
- read them using an external program which communicates with your webextension, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging
- make an export tool (external program) which exports to JSON (or something similar) and make an import option in your webextension

Aside from the options above, it was possible to have a hybrid webextension which could read the preferences and publish it on addons.mozilla.org, but that option expired as of Firefox 57 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This gave me another idea: tell users to go to `about:config`, find the preferences, and import them in an option page. May be easier than asking them to install something extra, and the data is useful but not critical.

Comment: Please note that you will not be able to query about:config when it is open, it will have to be a manual action entirely. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected if I go this way.