# Change FF Preferences with WebExtension API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, preferences, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to code a Firefox Extension with the Webextension API.
The Extension should deactivate HTML Canvas, WebGL, localStorage etc for privacy reasons.
I cant find any way how the Extension can change these preferences, anybody have some hints for me how i can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access old-style Firefox extension's preferences when porting to WebExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650400/access-old-style-firefox-extensions-preferences-when-porting-to-webextensions)

Comment: But there i cant find a soulution :/

Comment: As I said in that answer, you will need to make an external tool which communicates with native messaging, modifying the preferences file on disk.

Comment: The possible duplicate is not the correct duplicate. This is the question (and answer) you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023416/is-it-possible-to-create-a-firefox-webextension-that-changes-aboutconfig-settin/50024435